# Update output texts in gui without clicking in java

Tags: java

I am lookiing for a simple way to use java gui, that updates string outputs dynamically.
JOptionPane doesn't seem to be the option because of the button that the user keeps pressing.
For example: in a loop there is a string that is updated every time the loop runs,
"a" --> "b" --> "c" --> "d".
I need to display it in a gui one at a time but automatically without pressing any button and the programe will end when the loop ends

Comment: paint the string on a panel and repaint it after change. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Answer (score 0):

To update your GUI representation you may call the `repaint()` method of the corresponding component.